# LKM compiling - modpost syntax error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, syntax-error

i'm currently trying to compile a simple kernel module (just prints HelloWorld). But everytime when I try to compile it, I get the error : "

```
    scripts/Makefile.modpost:91: recipe for target '__modpost'  failed"
```

My makefile looks like the following:

```
    obj-m +=mod_init.o
    mod_init-y += Tests/breakpoint.o



    all:
            make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules -w
            @echo "Modules build"

    clean:
            make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

"Make clean" works flawlessly. But "make" always ends in this error.

My system runs on ARM with a self compiled kernel (Linux 4.11.4 from Kernel.org) I cross compiled it by using a second pc with the following commands:

PC2:

```
    export ARCH=arm
    export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-
    make mrproper
    make exynos_defconfig (exynos is my cpu on ARM + make menuconfig for my needs)
    make zImage (needed for my board)
    make modules
```

After this is copied the zImage (which boots according to uname -a)
and copied the source folder to /usr/src/ on the ARM board). There i executed this:

ARM Board:

```
    make modules_install
    make check_headers
    make headers_install
```

right after this i try to execute my makefile which won't end without the error.
Executing it with "make V=1" prints this (in addition to the above mentioned error):

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-4.11.4'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;

echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \

echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\

echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \

echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)

But these files are in /usr/src/linux-4.11.4/include/...

Searching for this problem i found this (goo.gl/IZHp4j) but rewriting the makefile won't change anything

Does anybody got an idea how to fix this? The only things i found refered to no installed headers (except my copied kernel source there is nothing in /usr/src) or not allowed signs in the makefile

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you check whether `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` on board points to `/usr/src` ?

Comment: You need to `export ARCH=arm` on ARM board as well, along with `make some_deconfig`.

Comment: thank you for your answers.
@vtha: build and source both a point to /usr/src/#LinuxVersion

        "build -> /usr/src/linux-4.11.4"
        "source -> /usr/src/linux-4.11.4"

Comment: @0andriy: i'm going to test this later with a new compiled version. just tried it with the current (already installed version) but this won't do anything except installing/checking one module. Is there a reason why i have to do the "make xxx_config"? Because the config file is just copied with everything else in the folder?

(Had to split my answer to two parts, because I could only @ one user...)